# help with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I go from this:

```
"01","35004","AL","ACMAR",86.51557,33.584132,6055,0.001499
```

to this:

```
ACMAR, AL
```

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you are trying to do? I can't figure it out based solely on your example.

Comment: Where is your regular expression? What are these things? Strings? A list of strings and numbers?

Comment: What led you to believe that a regular expression was the most appropriate way to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like the input string (a line of data) is from a CSV file, and the required output is the 4th field and the 3rd field separated by a 'comma space' sequence.  Sounds like just the job for a CSV package and probably not for a regex - unless perhaps (and only perhaps) you can be sure that quotes and commas will never appear in the data portion of the CSV notation.

Comment: That is a line(1 of 29,000) from a .txt file with US Census data.  That is the first line from the file.  I would like to change that line to Acmar, AL.  The 3rd field is the state, 4th is the city.  I would like to change all the lines to simply: city, state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you'd want to parse a CSV file with a `Regexp` instead of a CSV parser. It makes your life *so* much easier:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open('/path/to/output.csv', 'wt') do |csv|
  CSV.foreach('/path/to/output.csv') do |_, _, state, city|
    csv << [state, city]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is an array — `[…].grep(/^[A-Z]+$/)`, if string — `"…".scan(/[A-Z]+/)`

Answer (score 0):

match: \"([A-Za-z].*)\".*\"([A-Za-z].*)\"

replace: \2, \1

This assumes the only fields with letters are those two. A better solution might be to explode on ',' and take the 3rd and 4th string.

Comment: How would I run this?
\"([A-Za-z].*)\".*\"([A-Za-z].*)\".match("01","35004","AL","ACMAR",86.51557,33.584132,6055,0.001499) 

This is not right.

Comment: use the string sub function, something like this: localString.sub(/\"([A-Za-z].*)\".*\"([A-Za-z].*)\"/,"\2, \1");

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
"(.+)","(.+)","(.+)","(.+)",
```

and then concatenate capture group 3 and 2